# How to manipulate JSON data in Sails JS Controller

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to manipulate JSON data and return the modified data. However, its giving an error `ReferenceError: manufacturer_tab_list is not defined` even though the variable is defined.

```
getfields: function(req, res){
        Manufacturers.find({id: '5af01c0e712f4c05b27af99c'})
        .populate('manufacturer_tabs')
        .exec(function(err, manufacturer_tabs){
            var manufacturer_tabs_list = res.json(manufacturer_tabs);
            manufacturer_tabs_list[1].name = 'Tab 2';
            if(err){
                return res.json(err);
            }
            return manufacturer_tab_list;
        })                                                         
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the variable name , it's `manufacturer_tabs_list` not `manufacturer_tab_list`.

**EDIT**

```
getfields: function(req, res){
    Manufacturers.find({id: '5af01c0e712f4c05b27af99c'})
    .populate('manufacturer_tabs')
    .exec(function(err, manufacturer_tabs){
        manufacturer_tabs[1].name = 'Tab 2';
        if(err){
            return res.json(err);
        }
        return res.json(manufacturer_tabs);
    })                                                         
},
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo. But when I return the variable, it returns the data from `res.json(manufacturer_tabs)` and not the one that I manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to try this:

```
getfields: function(req, res){

   Manufacturers.findOne({id: '5af01c0e712f4c05b27af99c'})
    .populate('manufacturer_tabs')
    .exec(function(err, manufacturer){
        if(err){
            return res.serverError(err);
        }
        var manufacturer_tabs_list = _.cloneDeep(manufactuurer.manufacturer_tabs);
        manufacturer_tabs_list[1].name = 'Tab 2';
        return res.json(manufacturer_tab_list);
    })                                                         
},
```

I am using findOne instead of find to return a single manufacturer object where the manufacturer_tabs collection is a property of. Then I clone it so that is no longer a model object (if sails 1.0 then you won't need the _.cloneDeep() and could just mutate the data like manufacturer.manufacturer_tabs.name = 'Tab 2';).

I would put some additional error handling right after the first err condictional in there as well such as:

```
if (!manufacturer || !manufacturer.manufacturer_tabs || !manufacturer.manufacturer_tabs.length > 1) {
    return res.serverError('Can\'t find data'); 
}
```

Whatever works for you of course. Cheers